# getting a token between two different delimiters

Tags: c

I need to get the last character from a string. Say the string looks like this:

```
blue;5
```

I was thinking I could use strlen and then just subtract by 1 to get the 5. I have tried a bunch of different ways but none of them work. That's the way I have the way I think it should look or do, but I know that its not working. Any suggestions? This is sort of my code-pseudocode. I know it doesn't work for a variety of reasons but its sort of the flow I had in mind.

```
len = strlen(Input);
Position = Input[len - 1];
strcpy(value, Input[Position]);
```

Comment: There are [many nice string functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) in standard C. Some which can [help you find specific characters in a string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr).

Comment: As for the problem with using `strlen`, think about what `Input[len - 1]` actually *is*.

Comment: Your title is very different from what you ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 len = strlen(Input); //ok
```

Here you are going wrong . Putting a character into integer is incorrect. You need this.

```
 Position = Input[len - 1]; //incorrect
```

Do it as

```
 Position = strlen(Input) - 1 //correct

 strcpy(value, &Input[Position]);//ok
```

Comment: Actually, `strcpy` needs a pointer as its second argument. You pass it a char.

Comment: Oops @Paul Ogilvie thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the last character then you can use `strlen()` but not like that, instead like this

```
char string[] = "blue;5";
int position = strlen(string) - 1;
char last = string[position];

printf("%c\n", last);
```

note that `last` is not a string, but a single character which in turn is the ascii value for the last character in `string`, you can print it's representation using the `"%c"` `printf()` specifier.

Answer (score 0):

@Iharob has already posted some code that lets you access the last character as a *character*. But if you want a string, you can do this *because it is at the end, and so NUL-terminated:*

```
const char * lastword = string + (strlen(string) - 1);
printf("%s", lastword);
```

Note the '%s' - lastword is a "string", not a character. It's just a string that is one letter long.

Answer (score 0):

You are closer to the solution than you think:

```
    len = strlen(Input);
    strcpy(value, &Input[len - 1]);  // copy last character
```

`strcpy` needs a pointer to the last char.